# Python: выделение из строки подстрок с использованием нескольких разделителей

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, split

подскажите как лучше реализовать следующую задачу (чувствую, что можно обойтись одной лишь хитрой регуляркой):

есть строка слов, между некоторыми словами есть служебные слова AND или OR
например

```
text = "word1 word2 OR word3 AND word4 word5"
```

необходимо все группы слов между OR или AND преобразовать в виде key=(слова), слова OR или AND оставить на месте

т.е. в предыдущем примере должно получиться

```
text = "key=(word1 word2) OR key=(word3) AND key=(word4 word5)"
```

Comment: Буквально 10 минут назад хотел то же самое спросить, хех :) Вы угадали мои мысли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

txt = 'word1 word2 OR word3 AND word4 word5 OR ANDrey ORlando AND FORex'
out = re.sub(r'(\bOR\b|\bAND\b|^)\s*(.+?)\s*(?=\bOR\b|\bAND\b|$)', r' \1 key=(\2)', txt).strip()
print(out)
```

```
key=(word1 word2) OR key=(word3) AND key=(word4 word5) OR key=(ANDrey ORlando) AND key=(FORex)
```

Comment: супер, работает хорошо, вот только бы еще добавить чтоб OR/AND внутри слов не искал - это должны быть отдельные слова

Comment: @Zhihar добавил `\b`, ищет только отдельные слова OR|AND

Comment: Вот так покороче и логические операторы не дублируются `re.sub(r'(.+?)\s*((( (OR|AND) )\s*)|$)', r'key=(\1)\2', txt`

Answer (score 1):

Во так:

```py
import re
re.split('AND |OR ', string_to_split)
```

На enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998688/19509421

Comment: да, делит хорошо, но вот как соединить обратно, сохранив разделители?

Answer (score 0):

сделал так:

```
parts = re.split('(?<!\w)(AND|OR)(?!\w)', value)

output = [f"key=({parts[i].strip()})" if i % 2 == 0 else parts[i] for i in range(len(parts))]

res = ' '.join(output)
```